# How to use UIWebView that supports IPv6?

Tags: ios, networking, uiwebview, ipv6

I have an app that shows a content using `UIWebView`. Apple rejects the app, because it doesn't support IPv6 network. Do you have any idea how to fix that? I have to import some libraries or do something else?

I am not using IP address for the URL, but it's domain name, for example:

[https://asd.com](http://asd.com)

Comment: Firstly test if your link support ipv6 that apple mean from this link you can do it `http://ready.chair6.net`

Comment: My URL does not pass the test. I guess it's a problem, but in my country our providers does not support IPv6. So is there a solution in that case?

Comment: @scourGINHO: Your server doesn't need to support IPv6. An IPv4-only server will work fine. But if it does do IPv6, it needs to handle IPv6 correctly.

Comment: @user102008 What do you mean by that?

Comment: @scourGINHO: An IPv4-only server will work fine. Your server doesn't need to support IPv6. That's what I said. Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIWebView` not the reason of rejection the reason was your link or you server not support IPV6, Firstly test if your link support ipv6 that apple mean from this link you can do [it](http://ready.chair6.net) , If you not pass this test search for how to configuration your server to support IPV6, I hope I help you

Comment: No, your server doens't need to support IPv6

Comment: @user102008 Can you tell us how to handle it?!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There is nothing to "handle". It should just work fine if it's an IPv4-only server.

Comment: Not all server support IPV6 like AMAZON cloud server you can check it by your self from this link `http://ready.chair6.net`, and here how to handle your website to support IPV6 `http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2014/06/how-to-make-your-website-available-over-ipv6/`

Comment: Like I said, not supporting IPv6 is fine.

Answer (score -3):

If your application is targeting above iOS 8, try using WebKit instead of UIWebView.

Refer to the following link which clarifies the text below it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Note: "In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files that are not supposed to run JavaScript."